# Array Sorting on multiple elements

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sorting, indexing

I thought I'd rewrite this in order to make it a bit more clear and hopefully eliminate the confusion.

Les say I have several floors of offices. I want to sort those offices by the lowest number for each floor
so that the result look like this:

```
-------------------------
| floor | office | sort |
-------------------------
|   1   |   4    |   1  |
|   2   |   4    |   2  |
|   3   |   3    |   3  |
|   4   |   3    |   4  |
|   1   |   5    |   5  |
|   2   |   5    |   6  |
|   3   |   4    |   7  |
|   4   |   4    |   8  |
|   1   |   6    |   9  |
|   2   |   6    |  10  |
|   3   |   5    |  11  |
|   4   |   5    |  12  |
|   2   |   7    |  13  |
|   3   |   6    |  14  |
|   4   |   6    |  15  |
|   3   |   7    |  16  |
|   4   |   7    |  17  |
-------------------------
```

The array:

```
array ( 
0 => array ( 
            'floor' => 1, 
            'office' => 4, 
            ), 
1 => array ( 
            'floor' => 1, 
            'office' => 5, 
            ), 
2 => array ( 
            'floor' => 1, 
            'office' => 6, 
            ), 
3 => array ( 
            'floor' => 2, 
            'office' => 4, 
            ), 
4 => array ( 
            'floor' => 2, 
            'office' => 5, 
            ), 
5 => array ( 
            'floor' => 2, 
            'office' => 6, 
            ), 
6 => array ( 
            'floor' => 2, 
            'office' => 7, 
            ), 
7 => array ( 
            'floor' => 3, 
            'office' => 3, 
            ), 
8 => array ( 
            'floor' => 3, 
            'office' => 4, 
            ), 
9 => array ( 
            'floor' => 3, 
            'office' => 5, 
            ), 
10 => array ( 
            'floor' => 3, 
            'office' => 6, 
            ), 
11 => array ( 
            'floor' => 3, 
            'office' => 7, 
            ), 
12 => array ( 
            'floor' => 4, 
            'office' => 3, 
            ), 
13 => array ( 
            'floor' => 4, 
            'office' => 4, 
            ), 
14 => array ( 
            'floor' => 4, 
            'office' => 5, 
            ), 
15 => array ( 
            'floor' => 4, 
            'office' => 6, 
            ), 
16 => array ( 
            'floor' => 4, 
            'office' => 7, 
            )
, )
```

What I need to do is loop thru each floor one at a time and take the lowest numbered office and then start at back at the lowest numbered floor again until exhausted.

Comment: can you post a `print_r` instead of a `var_dump` of your array .. harder to test otherwise.

Comment: if you wanna make it easy to test use var_export()

Comment: I added an export above.. As I already included var_dump.

Comment: usort is the answer, but idk about the logic, hard to understand the the sorting logic you're after

Comment: I can explain it like this. In this array we have 4 heat races. these represent the riders that didn't make direct transfer to the main event. They need to be distributed into semi finals based on their finish position and the time of the heat. So the first rider in the fast heat = 1, first rider in second fast heat = 2 and so on. When we've been thru all of the heats taking the first rider, we move to the next rider in each heat.. until all are assigned a number. 

That will give me the lineup for the semi final races. convoluted sure, but that's how we do it.

Comment: Are these results coming from a database query? if so, which database engine is used?

Comment: Yep, mysql.. This is a 2 year old question. already got the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is the `usort` function. Something like

```
function racerCompare($a, $b) {
    if ($a['heat_nbr'] > $b['heat_nbr'}) {
        return -1;
    } else if ($a['heat_nbr'] < $b['heat_nbr'}) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
usort($startingArray, 'racerCompare');
```

with the `racerCompare` logic perhaps a little different (it's not completely clear form the question).

Comment: I get what you're doing there, but it's definitely not returning the right order.

Comment: race order is derived from the heat race times. I only display race time here for reference.. all you need to know is race_order and heat_finish. Those are the only fields that need to be considered for this sort.
each race_order take the first heat_finish, move to the next.. loop until they are exhausted.

Comment: I posted above with the results from the function you provided. Not sorting how it needs to.

Comment: I have tried every combination I can think of in that function to test and this is as close as I can get.. I changed the if to (if ($a['heat_finish'] < $b['heat_finish']) and the elseif to (else if ($a['race_order'] > $b['race_order']))